# Header div too big because of z-index?

Tags: html, css

I used z-index to layer images in my header, and now my header size is too big. Basically, the height is the same as it would be if all the images were layed out without being overlapped, but it ends up being just white space. As a result, the body overlaps with the header.

This is the page, it may make the most sense to just look at what I mean, but I can post the code if needed!

http://kerryaltmantest.info/hometest.html

ETA - Here's the CSS:

```
#header 
{ width: 1100px; margin:0 auto; background: #ffffff;}
#body
{width: 950px; margin:0 auto; background: #ffffff;}
#menu1 {
width: 890px; margin:0 auto; background: #ffffff;}
#content {
width: 930px; margin:0 auto; background: #ffffff;
border-left: 10px solid #2b297f;
border-right: 10px solid #2b297f;}

body {
background: #d0d0d0;}

.background
{
border: 0px ;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
left: -150px;
top: -30px
}

.mainheader
{
border: 0px;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
top: -185px;
left: 170px;
}
.phone
{ 
position: relative;
z-index: 3;
top: -298px;
left: 675px}
.email
{ 
position: relative;
z-index: 4;
top: -287px;
left: 720px}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="mainRunner"><img class="background" height="200" src="http://i.imgur.com/K1W98DF.png" width="800" /> <img class="mainheader" height="150" src="http://i.imgur.com/sdqMfWT.png" width="500" /></div>
    <div class="contactinfo"><img class="phone" height="40" src="http://i.imgur.com/5Wew8PC.png" width="250" /><br><a href="mailto:kerralt@aol.com"><img class="email" height="30" src="http://i.imgur.com/bXs6aht.png" width="200" /> </a></div></div>
```

Comment: Please do share the code instead of just a link to your site.

Comment: Sorry about that! The code is there now

Comment: What's it supposed to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have all of your images with position:relative, but based on your description, you don't want them to be relative, you want them to be absolute.

Change "relative" to "absolute" and re-adjust your "top:" property accordingly.

Example CSS:

```
#header 
{ width: 1100px; margin:0 auto; background: #ffffff; position:relative}
#body
{width: 950px; margin:0 auto; background: #ffffff;}
#menu1 {
width: 890px; margin:0 auto; background: #ffffff;}
#content {
width: 930px; margin:0 auto; background: #ffffff;
border-left: 10px solid #2b297f;
border-right: 10px solid #2b297f;}

body {
background: #d0d0d0;}

.background
{
border: 0px ;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
left: -150px;
top: -30px
}

.mainheader
{
border: 0px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
left: 170px;
}
.phone
{ 
position: absolute;
z-index: 3;
top:45px;
left: 675px}
.email
{ 
position: absolute;
z-index: 4;
top: 100px;
left: 720px}
```